# Nextcord button bot error tab error inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: nextcord

My code

```
@bot.command(name='support')
async def support(ctx):
    hi = Button(label="click me", style=ButtonStyle.blurple)
    subscribe = Button(label="subscribe", url="https://www.youtube.com/channel?sub_confirmation=1")

    async def hi_callback(interaction):
        hi = client.get_user(id)
          await hi.send("hello")


    hi.callback = hi_callback

    myview = View(timeout=180)
    myview.add_item(hi)
    myview.add_item(subscribe)
    
    await ctx.send("hi", view=myview)
```

My error

File main.py, line 27

hi = client.get_user(id)

tab error inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Answer (score 0):

So in order for you to make your command to work you are going to have to create a class that way you can call the URL to the Button.

Also since you are using a link you cannot use `style=ButtonStyle.blurple` you must use `style=ButtonStyle.link`

Your command should look something like this:

```
class SupportButton(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Button(style=ButtonStyle.link, url='https://www.youtube.com/channel?sub_confirmation=1', label="Click me!"))
        self.value = None

@bot.command(name='support')
async def support(ctx):
    view = SupportButton()
    await view.wait()
    if view is None:
        return
    elif view.value is True: #Debugging 
        await ctx.send("nothing")
    else:
        await ctx.send('Sorry there was a issue when processing your request')
```